# Linking foreign keys between tables

Tags: php, html, jquery, database, foreign-keys

I have two tables: TEMA e SOTTOTEMA.
In TEMA I have, as primary key, IDtema which is auto-increment.
I want it to be foreign key in the sottotema table and I wrote, in phpmyadmin, where I have my db,

```
ALTER TABLE sottotema ADD FOREIGN KEY (IDtema) REFERENCES tema (IDtema)
```

It doesn't give me errors, but the foreign key doesn't work.
I have predefined themes in a select option, and depending on the theme you choose, you can insert a sub-theme yourself.

```
       <select id = "tema" name = "tema">
           <option hidden></option>
           <option value = "Animali"> Animali</option>
           <option value = "Cucina"> Cucina </option>
           <option value = "Sport"> Sport </option>
           <option value = "Musica"> Musica </option>
           <option value = "Cinema"> Cinema </option>
           <option value = "Letteratura"> Letteratura </option>
       </select></br>
      
       <div id = "sottotema" style = "display:none">
           <p id = "titolosottotema"> Sottotema </p>
           <input type = "text" placeholder="Scrivi un sottotema" id = "st" name = "st"/>
       </div>
```

All this obviously is inside a FORM and everything works, except for inserting the IDtema as a foreign key, in the sottotema table.

I report only the data entry queries in the db, but in my php code there is something else written, including the connection to the db obviously

```
<?php
   
$sottotema = $_POST['st'];

$query = "INSERT INTO sottotemi (nomeSottotema) VALUES ('$sottotema')";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
if (!$result){​​​​​​
echo "errore 1";
}​​​​​​ else {​​​​​​
$query2 = "INSERT INTO blog (titoloBlog,nomeSottotema,nomeUtente,sfondo, font, colorefont) VALUES ('$titoloblog','$sottotema',(SELECT nomeUtente FROM utentiregistrati WHERE nomeUtente = '$nomeutente'),'$sfondo','$font','$colore');";
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2);
if(!$result2){​​​​​​
echo 'errore 2';
}​​​​​​

?>
```

In the db I have already entered my predefined themes, so the idtema, primary key, is already associated with a specific theme (eg 1 - Animali, etc.).
Please help me I'm desperate !!!!!

Comment: We would also need to see the PHP code that stores data in the database

Comment: But I would suggest that you place the `IDtema` value into the option `value=` attribute instead of the text

Comment: So write type `<option value = "1"> Animali</option>
                       <option value = "2"> Cucina </option>`?

Comment: Yes thats the idea, you will have to get the id's from the database, a select and loop to build your SELECT Dropdown

Comment: I'm not very experienced, so I don't know how to do otherwise.
Could you explain me with a code example?

Comment: Can you do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tema;` and copy/paste the output to your question so I know what to query

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `tema` (
 `IDtema` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `nomeTema` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`IDtema`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the foreign key to work you need to specify the foreign table identifier in the INSERT operation, otherwise the row would be orphan form the start.  Instead of `INSERT INTO sottotemi (nomeSottotema) VALUES ('$sottotema')` you'll need to find identifier (`IDtema`) to the foreign table (`tema`) and also provide it in the INSERT operation as follows (NOTE this is a different format of the `INSERT` statement that consumes the results of a `SELECT` statement instead of using the VALUES() version):

```html
INSERT INTO sottotemi
  (nomeSottotema, IDtema)
SELECT
  '$sottotema', T.IDtema
FROM tema AS T
WHERE T.nome = '$tema'
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is "T"? Tema? And then, in the INSERT Into, the SELECT would be inside VALUES right? Like INSERT INTO ... VALUES (SELECT...);?

Comment: 1) What is `T`? It is the alias of table `tema` declared by using `AS T`.

Comment: 2) Answer to the question about the `INSERT` statement: This is a different format of `INSERT`, you don't need `VALUES(...)`, you can consume the results of a `SELECT` statement instead.  NOTE: Of course, all this would work if your database engine supports this type of SQL which is quite standard but please verify.

Comment: It worked!! Really great, you have been very kind, thanks, thanks, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! :)